# boost 1_48 what bjam? error with bjam mismatched versions of Boost

Tags: unit-testing, testing, boost, bjam, quantlib

please help, I have WindowsXP, I have downloaded 3.1.18 bjam from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/ as it looks like the most recent (but is 2010?) becouse I can't run examples tests from QuantLib
the error is: cannot find libboost_unit_test_framework lib

so I run this bjam, but it says: mismatched versions of Boost. Build enggine and core.  is 03.1.18 , core is 2011.04-svn

what should I do? please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap.bat in the boost directory which creates the right bjam/b2 version for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem, fixed as the following: 
 1. check your %PATH%, is there mingw(or other GCC variant) path in it?
 2. if yes, then go into the folder, check if there is a file "bjam.exe"?
 3. if yes, then rename it.